# React and using ReactDOM.createPortal() - Target container is not a DOM element Error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on a React app and am trying to use `ReactDOM.createPortal()` to add html content to a div that is *outside* the component (called ToDoItem).

```
{ReactDOM.createPortal(
    <Route path={`/profile/project/${this.props.project._id}`} render={() => 
    <ProjectView project={this.props.project}/>}  />,
    document.getElementById('tasks')
)}
```

None of the HTML in the public folder is predefined - it is all dynamically created.

I think this could be the cause of the error: React tries to add HTML to the div with the id of `tasks` which, but the div is not loaded into the DOM before this happens?

If this method is incorrect, is there any other method I can use append html content to another div outside the component?

Some other info: the component from which I tried to run this method is a stateless component, not a class component.

This is the error:

[image]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can wait until the DOM is ready using `React.useEffect`, and then you call `ReactDOM.createPortal`:

```
function Component() { 
  const [domReady, setDomReady] = React.useState(false)

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setDomReady(true)
  }, [])

  return domReady 
    ? ReactDOM.createPortal(<div>Your Component</div>, document.getElementById('container-id')) 
    : null
}
```

Comment: You need to specify your useEffect only when the page is loading ```React.useEffect(() => {
    setDomReady(true)
  },[])```

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you can't createProtal to react component.
the second parameter have to be dom elemenet, not react created element

Answer (score 5):

I had this issue because I forgot to add `<div id="some-id"></div>` to my index.html file :-D

So just as a reminder for anyone who has a similar problem or doesn't know how to use React portals ( to create a modal for example):

in **modal.jsx**:

```
const modalRoot = document.getElementById('modal');

const Modal = () => {
  const modalElement = document.createElement('div');

  // appends the modal to portal once modal's children are mounted and 
  // removes it once we don't need it in the DOM anymore:
  useEffect(() => {
    modalRoot.appendChild(modalElement);
    return () => {
      modalRoot.removeChild(modalElement);
    };
  }, [modalElement]);

  return createPortal(<div>modal content</div>, modalRoot);
};
```

in **index.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    // head content
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    // dont't forget about this:
    <div id="modal"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

Before first render of components, there is no element in the `DOM` and `document.getElementById` cannot reach to any element. elements added to `DOM` after first render.

Use `useRef` in parent component and send it to `Portal Component`.

In parent component:

```
const tasksRef = React.useRef(null);
const [tasksSt, setTasksSt]= React.useState();

....
    <div  ref={
        (current) => {tasksRef.current = current;
                setTasksSt(tasksRef.current);
                }
            }/>
    <YourPortalComp tasksRef={tasksRef} />
```

In Portal Component

```
{this.props.tasksRef.current?(ReactDom.createPortal(<...>, this.props.tasksRef.current):null}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the target element (In your case element with id `tasks`) is loaded but still you are getting the `Target container is not a DOM element Error` error, you can try the below solution.

```html
const MyElement = () => {
  const [containerToLoad, setContainerToLoad] = useState(null);
  
  // If the target element is ready and loaded
  // set the target element
  useEffect(() => {
    setContainerToLoad(document.getElementById('container'));
  }, []);

  return containerToLoad && createPortal(<div>modal content</div>, containerToLoad);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

check your id in index.html file,
So lets say, your index.html file has:
`<div id="overlays"></div>`

Your Modal should point to same div, ie

```
const portalElement = document.getElementById('overlays');
const Modal = (props) => {
return (
    <Fragment>
      {ReactDOM.createPortal(<Backdrop onClose={props.onClose} />, portalElement)}
  </Fragment>
 );
```

};

Answer (score 0):

For those that might be using Next.js, an equivalent to AlexxBoro's answer for next js can be found here. https://www.learnbestcoding.com/post/101/how-to-create-a-portal-in-next-js